# Is it possible to add an option to open the Windows Clipboard History to the right click context menu?

Tags: windows, windows-10, context-menu, clipboard

I would like to be able to access the Windows 10 [clipboard-history](https://www.howtogeek.com/351978/using-windows-10s-new-clipboard-history-and-cloud-sync/) function (currently opened by pressing the Windows key + v) by right-clicking and picking it from the context menu. Is this possible?

The only [guide](https://winaero.com/blog/clipboard-history-context-menu-windows-10/) that I have found that is related to this gives you the option to enable or disable the feature when right-clicking on the desktop, as opposed to actually opening it up to copy things from it.

Any help that you can give will be greatly appreciated.

Liam

Comment: Winaero Tweaker will let you do that. It's freeware, and you can find it here (https://winaero.com/download.php?view.1796). Use the search bar to find the tweak that'll place clipboard history in the context menu. I suppose that since it's a GUI tweak, there must be an underlying way to do it otherwise, via Registry or CLI, but I don't know how, I'm sorry.

Comment: I think that Winaero Tweaker is the same thing that I have already tried in the above post, but the one I used was just one specific tweak from the collection. It only seems to be able to add the history function the desktop context menu, but thank you for recommending the tweaker it seems as though it will be very useful.

Comment: Have you tried this command in PowerShell? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-clipboard

Comment: You can also try this third-party by a reputable vendor: https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/inside_clipboard.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible.
You're trying to bring things together which work at different levels.
The clipboard is a feature of the operating system.
The right-click behaviour is given by the active application-window in which you are clicking.

Even if a lot of software has context-menus, the implementation of these menus vary greatly. A right- click in Word is not handled in tbe same way as in your browser.
In some software, such as Autocad, right-click can mean 'escape' or 'enter', depending on context, and there is not any context menu.

You might be able to assign it to the context menu of SOME SPECIFIC software, but ONLY IF the programmer of such software has foreseen this possibility.

Only if you have a mouse with more than two buttons, you might assign to a third button a function of your choice.  But mostly this capability depends on the specific driver of the mouse manufacturer. (Example: on the Logitech MX series you can reassign some of the buttons).
If you want to reformulate your question in such sense, there might be some solution.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a Logitech Master 3S Mouse, remap (called 'Keyboard Shortcut' in Logi Options+ software) any of the custom buttons to key combination (Windows+V) and when you click that button, the Clipboard will pop up!

Answer (score 0):

i know it might not be what you are looking for, but its the CLOSEST thing i have found,
use the microstoft tool "windows powertoys", https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/

there is a feature there that allows you to remap your keyboard as you please,
and loads of keyboards have a button that activated the right click menu on them somewhere, (mine is near the arrow keys), i have literally NEVER used it, as my mouse has a right click on it,

but using that keyboard remapper utility you can map that button, to the win+v combo to make it open your clipboard, the symbol most keyboards use for that button even still works to symbolize what it does too.

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering the same exact thing which is how I ended up here. The only thing I could come up with is to use Windows key + Ctrl + o to bring up the On-Screen Keyboard where I can press the Windows key + v to bring up the clipboard without having to touch the physical keyboard. The On-Screen Keyboard says on the screen and stays wherever you drag it on your screen. You can also make it whatever size you would like. You can turn on the On-Screen keyboard in settings under Ease of Access ->Interaction -> Keyboard.